# How to access home appliances consumption?

Tags: google-smart-home, nest-device-access

I'd like to develop a system similar to Nest Renew in the US, that is a system able to offset electricity consumption to when the electricity grid has enough renewables power. Is it possible to access the total heater/cooling systems energy consumption with the Device Access API ?

I'd like to get their current consumption, and report it to a third-party service, is there any way I could do this, or compute it from the settings information ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you realize your proposed system will consume electricity as well?

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is not possible to access the total heater/cooling systems energy consumption using the device access APIs. I would recommend opening up a feature request in this regard on the [Public Issue Tracker](https://b.corp.google.com/).